# Can a subclass access a superclass' private members?

Tags: java, oop, package, private

In Java, class A defines a member variable `private int num;` Class B is a subclass of class A.

1- If the two classes are **in the same package** - does B inherit `num`?

2- If the two classes are **not in the same package** - does B inherit `num`?

Comment: Have you tried? That would have probably taken less than writing the questions here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private?rq=1

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: `private modifier`—the field is accessible only within its own class.

Comment: Do not understand pseudo-code or any human language, only understand code. Please show code.

Comment: You know, in the time this question will be downvoted and closed, you could have found out for yourself by *writing some code* rather than asking people to tell you the answer.

Comment: @NambiNarayanan Is there a way to allow a field/method to be inherited by subclasses, but not accessible by any other class? I.e., only accessible by the subclasses?

Comment: @Prog  Use the `protected` modifier for that.

Comment: @NambiNarayanan But that allows all classes in the package access, which pretty much brakes encapsulation. If this is the only option, it's a problem with Java isn't it?

Comment: @Prog I think the idea is that a package is something you create to bundle up closely related types that cooperate with each other.  Another programmer using your package might extend (subclass) one of your types, but he wouldn't define a new type in your package.  So in this scenario, it would be considered OK for members to be accessible to other classes, but only the closely related ones.  See also [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**B** does not inherit or have access to `num` in either of those cases.

Answer (score 0):

In any case a subclass can access to a method or variable if this is declared as `private` in a superclass.

The only way to allow access to your `num` field is providing `public` (or at least `protected`) accessors method:

```
public int getNum(){
    return this.num;
}

public void setNum(int num){
    return this.num = num;
}
```